# Would it be out of line to systematically ask a user if they've actually stepped through the code?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can we tell people that what they need is a debugger?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86885/how-can-we-tell-people-that-what-they-need-is-a-debugger)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Object+not+set+to+instance+%5Bc%23%5D

The C# tag gets several questions per week with the title "Object reference not set to instance of object" or "NullReferenceException" and invariably the answer is *always* either

- This thing is very obviously null, fix it
- or we can't tell, you're just going to have to step through it in your debugger

With the volume of questions that come in for precisely this runtime exception, is it worth showing a system message beforehand that this is a common error and the user should learn to debug? I don't know if you guys have a "common problem -> show message" feature, but if you do, add this. If you don't, add one, and add this.

Comment: I usually vote to close those as Too Localized if they've received 1 answer pointing out what is likely (enough) to be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a user types this title into the new question page, they see this:

[image]

So it's fair to say that they already have *some* idea that the question has been asked (and probably answered) before.

You could also find the variant of this question with the best answer posted, and link it as one of the frequently-asked-questions about the C# tag in the [Tag Wiki.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info)

Comment: I agree, they'll see that, and yet somehow they think to themselves "my question is... *different*, Ms. Gump." Maybe 1% actually fall into an area of subtlety, but most are the of garden variety, "seriously, fire up your debugger" sort.